# RxSwift can't find flatMapObservable

Tags: swift, rx-swift

> Single.flatMapObservable

in RxSwift is it called differently or it just doesn't exist?

Comment: I think the `flatMap` is what are you looking for, since `Single` in RxSwift is simply a variation of Observable

Answer (score 1):

To convert `Single<E>` into `Observable<E>`, simply the `flatMap` operator is what you're looking for.

On the other hand if you want to convert from `Observable<E>` to `Single<E>`, you can do so like this:

```
Observable<Int>.just(1)
  .flatMap { number -> Single<Int> in
    return Single<Int>.just(number)
  }
  // it's Single<Int> from now on..
```

Comment: there is no `flatMapSingle` in the RxSwift. to convert single to observable you should use the `.asObservable()`

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. I've been working way too much in RxKotlin lately, edited.